# single space as field separator with awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I am dealing with a file where fields are separated by a single space.

awk interprets the FS `" "` as "one or more whitespace", which misreads my file when one of the fields is empty.

I tried using "a space not followed by a space"( `" (?! )"` ) as FS but awk does not support negative lookahead. Simple google queries like "single space field separator awk" only sent me to the manual page explaining the special treatment of `FS=" "`. I must have missed the relevant manual page...

How can I use a single space as field separator with awk?

Comment: I had actually opened the relevant manual page... https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html

Comment: `FS can be set to "[ ]" to use a single space as field separator.`

Comment: `awk -F'[ ]' '{printf ">%s<",$2}' <<< 'a       b'` doesn't work for me, I'm using gawk

Comment: Uh, looks like the commend system slurped the newlines. I actually use `<<< 'a[space][space][space][space]b'` as input

Comment: I meant "slurped the whitespaces".

Comment: @hek2mgl I get the output I expect, i.e. `><`.  If that is not what you expect, your *expectations* are wrong.

Comment: @antoine-sac Can you post a few lines of your content and what you expect the fields to be?  Please pay close attention on the empty field, whether it's a null string or additional white space.

Comment: @tripleee Please read the question carefully. OP reports that in his data there are fields which containing whitespace only.

Comment: @hek2mgl I have reread the question twice and if anything, I think your reading is incorrect.  The OP specifically asks about an empty field.  I see nothing about fields containing whitespace.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, looks like you are right. My fault.

Comment: @tripleee @hek2mgl As triplee says, I never have whitespace in my fields, but some fields are empty. Setting FS to `"[ ]"` worked for me and I am using gawk! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

this should work

```
$ echo 'a    b' | awk -F'[ ]' '{print NF}'
5
```

where as, this treats all contiguous white space as one.

```
$ echo 'a    b' | awk -F' ' '{print NF}'
2
```

based on the comment, it need special consideration, empty string or white space as field value are very different things probably not a good match for a white space separated content.

I would suggest preprocessing with `cut` and changing the delimiters, for example

```
$ echo 'a    b' | cut -d' ' -f1,3,5 --output-delimiter=,
a,,b
```

Comment: It sounds like OP wants `3` instead of `5` because the two spaces enclosed by the delimiter are a field - a field containing two spaces.

Comment: @hek2mgl Uh, no, there is no way for a field to contain the field separator.  When the field separator is a single space, two adjacent spaces are separators around an empty field.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah. I still think the question is interesting, I mean it is generally a valid use case, however I would have chosen a different delimiter in that case.

Comment: @karafka Nice idea to change the delimiters, but I don't have any whitespace in my fields so the first solution was sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To give a couple of helpful manpage references for this behaviour:

[Default Field Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html) explains that `" "` is the default value, but carries a special meaning:

> The default value of the field separator `FS` is a string containing a single space, `" "`.
>
> If awk interpreted this value in the usual way, each space character would separate fields, so two spaces in a row would make an empty field between them.
>
> The reason this does not happen is that **a single space as the value of `FS` is a special case**—it is taken to specify the default manner of delimiting fields.

[Regexp Field Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html) explains how delimit a single space:

> For a less trivial example of a regular expression, try using single spaces to separate fields the way single commas are used. `FS` can be set to `"[ ]"` (left bracket, space, right bracket).
>
> **This regular expression matches a single space and nothing else** (see [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html)).

(Added the emphasis and paragraphing.)