# awk with empty field in columns

Tags: awk

Here my `file.dat`

```
1   A 1 4
2     2 4
3   4 4
3     7 B
1   U 2
```

Running `awk '{print $2}' file.dat` gives:

```
A
2
4
7
U
```

But I would like to keep the empty field:

```
A

4

U
```

How to do it?

I must add that between :

- column 1 and 2 there is 3 whitespaces field separator
- column 2 and 3 and between column 3 and 4 one whitespace field separator

So in column 2 there are 2 fields missing (lines 2 and 4) and in column 4 
there are also 2 fields missing (lines 3 and 5)

Comment: It might help with GNU awk and mawk to set field separator to exact one space: `awk -F ' ?' '{print $2}' file`

Comment: In my file the exact field separator between two column  is not constant (could be one two or sevaral whitespace)

Comment: @olivierdadoun  In that case, how do you define the `second column`?

Comment: With `Procedural Text Edit` you can use `forEach line {
   select (firstN char 2) {remove}
   select (afterN char 1) {remove}
}`

Comment: if the field separator is not constant how do you know in second row second field is blank?  it may we well that there are multiple white spaces between first and second fields.

Comment: @tiw this a very good point :) I have checked, indeed between two columns the space are constant.

Comment: @karakfa you have right, I will modify my exemple

Comment: Are the numbers in column 1 always single-digit numbers?  Are the values in the other columns always a single character?

Comment: I suggest: Find the row with the most columns. In this row determine all column spacing and save it in an array. With this information you can find out in all rows where a column is empty.

Comment: In GNU Awk, the manual has a section on [Reading fixed-width data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size).  It's hard to tell whether that will be helpful to you.

Comment: From your comments, we get the definition "3 space between column 1 and 2; 1 space between any other column". This means that  In your current example, rows 1 and 5 have 4 columns, rows 2 and 4 have 5 columns, and row 3 has  3 columns. I don't think that's what you actually mean to happen, so your example and definition are inconsistent

Comment: similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36011760/1435869

Comment: @Cyrus `awk -F ' ?' '{print $2}' file` means the same in any awk and it doesn't mean "set field separator to exact one space" it means set FS to zero or 1 blank chars but YMMV with what any awk actually tries to do given that setting. To get 1 blank as the FS in any awk is `awk -F'[ ]' '...'`.

Comment: Your change makes it even fuzzier... Well, do the lines have same fields number, i.e. same columns?

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ awk -F'[ ]' '{print $4}' file
A

4

U
```

then edit your question to provide a more truly representative example and clearer requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is fixed-width columns, you can use `substr` to extract the slice you want.  I have assumed that you want a single character at index 5:

```
awk '{ print(substr($0,5,1)) }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` code is missing field separators.

Your example file doesn't clearly show what that field separator is.

From observation your file appears to have 5 columns.

You need to determine what your field separator is first.

This example code expects `\t` which means `<TAB>` as the field separator.

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $3}' OFS='\t' file.dat
```

This outputs the 3rd column from the file. This is the 'read in' field separator `-F'\t'` and `OFS='\t'` is the 'read out'.

```
A

4

U
```

Answer (score 0):

For GNU awk. It processes the file twice. On the first time it examines all records for which string indexes have only space and considers continuous space sequences as separator strings building up [`FIELDWIDTHS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html#Fixed-width-data). On the second time it uses that for fixed width processing of the data.

`a[i]`:s get valus 0/1 and `h` (header) with this input will be 100010101 and that leads to `FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2 1"`:

```
1   A 1 4
2     2 4
3   4 4
3     7 B
1   U 2
|   | | |
100010101 - while(match(h,/10*/))
 \ /|/|/|     
  4 2 2 1
```

Script:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    for(i=1;i<=length;i++)                              # all record chars
        a[i]=((a[i]!~/^(0|)$/) || substr($0,i,1)!=" ")  # keep track of all space places
    if(--i>m)
        m=i                                             # max record length...
    next
}
BEGINFILE {
    if(NR!=0) {                                         # only do this once
        for(i=1;i<=m;i++)                               #  ... used here
            h=h a[i]                                    # h=100010101
        while(match(h,/10*/)) {                         # build FIELDWIDTHS
            FIELDWIDTHS=FIELDWIDTHS " " RLENGTH         # qnd
            h=substr(h,RSTART+RLENGTH)                       
        }
    }
}
{ 
    print $2                                            # and output 
}' file file
```

And output:

```
A

4 

U
```

You need to trim off the space from the fields, though.